# Counting the length of an array with a function C

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, char

I have an error with my code , I am trying to write a function that counts the length of characters of a string. I am trying to place the string into an array so that I could use a function to return the length of the string. If the user inputs `dad` the program prints `len of string value: 3` and so on. Error `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`.

Function for the length of strings:

```
int stringcounter(a){
    int count;
    while (true){
        if (a[count] != NULL){
            ++count;
        }
        else{break;}
    }
    return count;
}
```

Main function

```
int main(void) {
    char text[100];  //string
    char str[100]={0};  // storing the text string
    printf("Enter an interesting string of less than %d characters:\n", 100);
    scanf("%s",text);
    str[1] = text; 
    stringcounter(str);

    printf("len of string value: %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the compiler is complaining that it's not a vector, then you are not compiling the code as C.  Perhaps you want to change the tag to C++, or instruct your compiler to stop trying to compile the code as C++.

Comment: Rather than just giving the size limit in the prompt, you might want to enforce it. `scanf("%99s", text);`

Comment: It's not at all clear what you hope to accomplish with `str[1] = text`.  Perhaps you wanted `strcpy`.

Comment: I am trying to write the program in C no tin C++. The function works fine however I just don't know how to pass the inputted string to the `stringcounter`.

Comment: If you instend to write the program in C then you must be sure to compile it with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.  The two are different languages.  The diagnostic you received suggests that you are using a C++ compiler instead, although it's not conclusive about that.  That could even be an effect of the file name -- the conventional extension for C source files is `.c` (lowercase), and some compilers will treat `.C` (uppercase) as indicating C++ source.

Comment: I am aware, I am using a C compiler and yes my extension is `.c`. I only have a problem with passing the inputted function to the function.

Comment: Your `stringcounter()` function must declare the type of its parameter `a`.  Probably you want `int stringcounter(char *a)`.  But no, that's not your only problem.

Comment: yes it is with the main void function I think although not sure as to what it is. I have applied the `int stringcounter(char *a)`

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes. First initialise count in function to 0: `int count = 0;` because it is set to any value if you don't init it. Secondly, count variable in stringcounter function is only in scope of stringcounter function you can't access it in main, for that look up global variables but they should be used rarely and with caution.
You are not storing the returned value from function anywhere so store it in some variable. Than try to avoid while(true) as much as you can because you can end in endless loop. Your condition can be your if, so while char is not NULL. 
Also with str[1] you are accessing one character, you would need array of pointers for it to be array of strings. I guess you are just beginning so it's too advanced, you don't need `str[1] = text;` at all. You can just init string for example as you did with text, take input in it, than send it in a funciton, calc the length and return it in some variable. There is no need for second string variable. And yeah, you need to declare the parameter type. You can use either `int stringcoutner(char *a)` or `int stringcounter(char a[])`.
I didn't want to write you the solution but I hope it helps a bit.